# All Javascript/ CSS and image will not render once deployed to remote tomcat but will not local tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am using tomcat 8 and once I take the war file and place it in my webapps folder all I get is HTML. You can see the site at [HERE](http://www.stidhamfinancial.com).

I am trying to do it like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.linkify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/../javascripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
```

I even tried to remove the `/../` but that didn't help.

head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

    <title>Stidham Financial</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../css/superfish.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../css/nivo-slider.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../css/jquery.qtip.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../css/jquery.fancybox.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"/>
```

[image: File Structure]

[image: war file structure]

Comment: Can you please the share the folder structure within WAR ? The above folder screen shot seems to be that of the original code. Moreover, for every static request, one of the response headers is **X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u6**. And none of the static requests (CSS, JS, images) end up into 404. If your Tomcat server is behind a proxy, can you please check (or share) your proxy configurations.

Comment: Please see the post, I updated it. I have a apache2 server running on port 80 and a reverse proxy in apache2 towards port 8080. Is that what you were referring too? I am also using thymeleaf if that matters.

Comment: Thanks for WAR directory structure. From the image it seems that the 'static' content is within **WEB-INF**. By default these files will not be available, until you have some specialized 'static content handler' servlet to cater pull these files from within WEB-INF. If you move the static folder outside WEB-INF, the files will be available with the URL http://www.stidhamfinancial.com/stidhamfinancial/static/... . So, you need to change the packing of the web archive. Moreover, the leading backslash anyways need to be removed. It would be helpful if you can try this and share the results.